# convert Image to base64 without uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64

i want to save image in localStorage in base 64 format.I know it using Filereader concept like this

```
function loadImageFileAsURL()
{
    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;

    if (filesSelected.length > 0)
    {
        var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];


        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
        {
        alert(fileLoadedEvent);

            document.getElementById("textAreaFileContents").innerHTML = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        };

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    }
}
```

but the problem is that i dont want upload any file. I just want to convert existing image into base64.Hope someone can help it

Comment: replace 'document.getElementById("textAreaFileContents").innerHTML=' with 'localStorage.myImg='

Comment: Draw image on canvas, then get canvas data as base64. There are a lot of articles about it in Internet

Comment: @dandavis thanks but how to convert this to base64 string without uploading the image

Comment: @ajeetlakhani: i don't understand, dataURLs are already base64 encoded. if you want  just the pure bytes without the mime, use url.split(",").pop() to get everything after the comma

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it's kind off possible ;)

1. Create canvas element
2. Load your image onto it
3. Run `canvas.toDataURL()` (base64 encoded image)
4. Save it locally or anywhere you want